# How can I dynamically call a function with a controller that is called dynamically?

Tags: php, function, dynamic, controller, router

I'm trying to impove my mini web site by implementing a dynamic router so I did the following

```
<?php

use App\Controller\Autoloader;
use App\Controller\PostController;
require_once("controller/Autoloader.php");

Autoloader::register(); 


$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url = explode('/', $url);
array_shift($url);
$base = $url[0];
$url = $url[1];
$page = "";
$function = "";
$controller = "";
 $urlArray = array(
'base' => $base,
'page' => $page,
'parameters' => array(
    "controller" => $controller,
    "function" => $function
)
 );
 $url = explode("?", $url);
 $urlArray["page"] = $url[0];


 $url = explode("&", $url[1]);

 $urlArray['parameters']['controller'] = str_replace("controller=", "",       $url[0]);
 $urlArray['parameters']['function'] = str_replace("action=", "", $url[1]);

 $controllerName = $urlArray['parameters']['controller'];
 $controller = new $controllerName();

 $controller->$urlArray['paremeters']['function']();
```

Since my url is **cleperduv2/index.php?controller=PostController&action=listPosts**

I want to call the function listPosts on the controller PostController.php

**( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'PostController' not found in C:\wamp64\www\cleperduv2\index.php on line 40**

Comment: Are you loading the `PostController`'s class? why don't you use a framework?

Comment: Looks like your controller is in `App/Controller/PostController`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes my controller is in App/Controller/PostController and just to make sure, the autoloader I created loads all the classes with the static router (that contains only if conditions). Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: And it doesn't work even when I set directly my varible containing the name of controller like $controllerName = "PostController";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's something with namespacing,
Have you tried to call it like this:

`$namespace = "App\Controller\\";
$controllerName = $namespace . $urlArray['parameters']['controller'];
$controller = new $controllerName;`

You can drop down the use namespace statement for the PostController and this way ll of your controllers will be required, declared, and instanciated dynamically as you want !

Answer (score 0):

Yo should really use the full path to the controller if you want php to interpret the class name;

İnsted of this:

```
$controller = new $controllerName();
```

Use this:

```
$controller = new "App\Controller\PostController";
```

If you ever use laravel, you may notice, in larevels routes, controllers are specified by the full class name. ie:

```
Route::get('/myIndexPage', 'Namespace1\Namespace2\MyController@index');
```

So, by the same principle, you better follow a convention to define your controllers in the same namespace, so you can do this:

```
$controller = new "App\Controllers\$controllerName";
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but now I got this on the same line !
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\wamp64\www\cleperduv2\index.php on line 40

Comment: you probably escaped a double quote without noticing. Can you post your 40th line ?

Comment: Here it is : $controller = new "App/Controller/$controllerName";

Comment: Notice that I use "use namespace App\Controller\PostController; which is userd afterwards by an autoloader

Comment: try with the backslashes, and that doesn't work, post your file and let me take a look.